# How to optimize this code to calculate YoY average by group_by in R?

Tags: r

I have this code:

```
df<-structure(list(YEAR = c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
 2020, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2013, 2014, 
 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020), Country = c("Brazil", "Brazil", 
 "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Finland", 
 "Finland", "Finland", "Finland", "Finland", "Finland", "Finland", 
 "Finland", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan", 
 "Japan", "Japan"), Value = c(51.7, 49.7, 46.6, 46.7, 37.4, 40.3, 
 42.5, 40, 76.7, 80.3, 82.8, 82.8, 78.6, 77.4, 74.7, 75.8, 67.1, 
 66, 66.7, 66.7, 62.5, 62.3, 64.5, 62.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -24L))

Y1=2013
Y2=2020
Ctr="*."

library(data.table)

setDT({df %>%
    dplyr::filter(grepl(Ctr,Country) &  YEAR %in% c(2013:2020)) %>%
    group_by(Country) %>% 
    arrange(YEAR, .by_group = TRUE)}
    )[, .(Country, YEAR, yoy = round((Value-shift(Value))/shift(Value)*100, digits = 2))] %>% 
    summarise(Country = c(Country, "Country"), YEAR = c(YEAR, 'Average'), across(starts_with('yoy'), ~ c(., {mean(., na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(2)})))
```

[image]

In my code I could not print the expected result equal to lines 9, 18, 27 and 28.

Another problem with my code is calculating the wrong average (output result: line 25) the correct one is the expected output value (line 28).

Is it possible to optimize the code to bring the expected output as generally as possible?

*Note: the countries and years are a small example, I think of creating a function later passing the following variables: RangeYear, Country or Group_Country(Ex. North American country group)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky but can be done.

First, let's declare the 'Years' like this so that it can scale in a better way:

```
Y1 <- min(df$YEAR)
Y2 <- max(df$YEAR)
```

```
#Calculate the YoY and save it in a different Data frame

df %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(YoY = 100 * (Value - lag(Value)) / lag(Value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(YEAR = as.character(YEAR),
         Value = as.character(Value)) -> df1

output_df <- data.frame()

#Run a loop to do everything for different Countries and add the results

for (x in unique(df1$Country)) {
  YEAR_x <- paste0(Y1,':',Y2)
  Country_x <- paste0(x,'_result')
  Value_x <- 'Average'
  
  df1 %>%
    filter(Country==x) %>%
    mutate(average=mean(YoY, na.rm=T)) %>%
    distinct(average) %>%
    pull()-> YoY_x
  
  output_df %>%
    bind_rows(df1 %>%
                filter(Country == x) %>%
                bind_rows(
                  data.frame(
                    YEAR = YEAR_x,
                    Country = Country_x,
                    Value = Value_x,
                    YoY = YoY_x
                  )
                )) -> output_df
  
  
    
  
}

#Calculate the overall average

output_df %>%
  filter(Value == 'Average') %>%
  pull(YoY) %>%
  mean(na.rm = T) -> YoY_all

#Final output

output_df %>%
  bind_rows(data.frame(
    YEAR = YEAR_x,
    Country = 'Country_result',
    Value = 'Average',
    YoY = YoY_all
  )) %>%
  select(Country, YEAR, Value, YoY) -> final_output

final_output
```

**Output**

```
          Country      YEAR   Value         YoY
1          Brazil      2013    51.7          NA
2          Brazil      2014    49.7  -3.8684720
3          Brazil      2015    46.6  -6.2374245
4          Brazil      2016    46.7   0.2145923
5          Brazil      2017    37.4 -19.9143469
6          Brazil      2018    40.3   7.7540107
7          Brazil      2019    42.5   5.4590571
8          Brazil      2020      40  -5.8823529
9   Brazil_result 2013:2020 Average  -3.2107052
10        Finland      2013    76.7          NA
11        Finland      2014    80.3   4.6936115
12        Finland      2015    82.8   3.1133250
13        Finland      2016    82.8   0.0000000
14        Finland      2017    78.6  -5.0724638
15        Finland      2018    77.4  -1.5267176
16        Finland      2019    74.7  -3.4883721
17        Finland      2020    75.8   1.4725569
18 Finland_result 2013:2020 Average  -0.1154371
19          Japan      2013    67.1          NA
20          Japan      2014      66  -1.6393443
21          Japan      2015    66.7   1.0606061
22          Japan      2016    66.7   0.0000000
23          Japan      2017    62.5  -6.2968516
24          Japan      2018    62.3  -0.3200000
25          Japan      2019    64.5   3.5313002
26          Japan      2020    62.4  -3.2558140
27   Japan_result 2013:2020 Average  -0.9885862
28 Country_result 2013:2020 Average  -1.4382429
```